# Match activeIndex of two swipers

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am playing around with swiper and I was wondering, is there a way to match activeIndexes of two different swipers?

The idea is to have two swipers on the page displaying images and when you slide one, other follows.

I have tried with swiper1.params.control = swiper2, but that is not really working because swiper1 has three slides per view and swiper2 has only one, so they don't really sync.

So, I started playing around with  mySwiper.activeIndex but something is not working.

I am using http://idangero.us/swiper/, version swiper@3.4.2

Here is my code

```
const swiper1 = new Swiper(swiper-one-container, {
    speed: 500,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    prevButton: '.left-arrow',
    nextButton: '.right-arrow',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    loop: false,
});

const swiper2 = new Swiper(swiper-two-container, {
    speed: 500,
    spaceBetween: 250,
    prevButton: '.left-arrow',
    nextButton: '.right-arrow',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: false,
    centeredSlides: true,
});

swiper1.slideTo(swiper2.activeIndex);

console.log(swiper1.activeIndex);
console.log(swiper2.activeIndex);
```

Comment: Swiper, no swiping!

Comment: Which Swiper library are you using? [http://idangero.us/swiper/](http://idangero.us/swiper/)?

Comment: Yes, version 3.4.2 because version 4 did not play nice with IE